# I want go get many items from FilterStore in Simpy Python

Tags: python, simpy

I want to get many items from FilterStore .

```
factory.stock_part.items
```

FilterStore is list type

```
[{'order_id': 534066215, 'id': 0}, {'order_id': 534066215, 'id': 1}, {'order_id': 534066215, 'id': 2}, {'order_id': 534066215, 'id': 3}, {'order_id': 534066215, 'id': 4}, {'order_id': 534066215, 'id': 5}, {'order_id': 534066215, 'id': 6}, {'order_id': 534066215, 'id': 7}, {'order_id': 534066215, 'id': 8}]
```

and I want to use:
factory.stock_part.get()

to get five items

```
factory.stock_part.get(5)
```

is not work.

How do I resolve this? Here's the full code:

```
import simpy


class Factory():
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.stock_part = simpy.FilterStore(env, capacity = 100000)
        


def stock_out(env,factory):
    while True:
        yield env.timeout(10)

        #in here I hope the inventory reduce 3，but one of the following 3 lines is not work
        factory.stock_part.get(5)
        factory.stock_part.get()[0:3]
        factory.stock_part.get(factory.stock_part.items[0:3])
        
        
            
            
    
env = simpy.Environment()

factory = Factory(env)

#create inventory list
factory.stock_part.put({'id':1})
factory.stock_part.put({'id':2})
factory.stock_part.put({'id':3})
factory.stock_part.put({'id':4})
factory.stock_part.put({'id':5})


on_process = env.process(stock_out(env, factory))

print('start')
env.run(until = 300)
print('end')
```

Comment: What is the error message? If it is a simple list, you can use list slicing: `factory.stock_part[:5]` to get the first 5. What has FilterStore to do with the code you have shown? [mre]!

Comment: factory.stock_part.get(factory.stock_part[:2])
*** TypeError: 'FilterStore' object is not subscriptable

Comment: factory.stock_part.get(factory.stock_part.items[0:5])
*** TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Please post a [mre] that we can run that mimics your datastructure so we can help.Curerntly this is a guessing game nobody benefits from.

Comment: Thanks for your response.But factory.stock_part.get(factory.stock_part[:2]) or factory.stock_part.get(factory.stock_part.items[0:5]) is not work.

Comment: I have posted a minimal code in answer list.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where is your eval function?

If you are using a filterStore, then don't need to pass in a function that will evaluate each resource and returns True when it finds a match?

something like

```
part = yield factory.stock_part.get(lambda part: part['id'] == 5)
```

filter stores only return one element at a time